# Lexicographical value

Tags: python, string, string-matching

i have a string. I need to replace the character '?' and find the missing character to make it lexicographical string. for Example- if I have string "ab". Its lexicographical value is "aa".Since the first character 'a' is different than second character 'b'. It gives output -1. If I give string "ta?a". In this  string If I replace '?' with t. It become lexicographical. It gives output "tata". I am giving input s and k. K is half of length of s. Please help me in this code.

```
s=input()
k=input()
for i in range(k):
    if (s[i]>=97) and (s[i]<=123):
        if (s[i]==s[i+k]):
            continue
        else:
             s=-1
    
    else:   
        if(s[i]>=s[i+k]):
            s[i+k]=s[i]
        else:
            s[i]=s[i+k]

return s
```

Comment: what means `lexicographical value` ?

Comment: what wrong with your code? Do you get wrong result? Show what you get and what you expect. Do you get error? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you can always use `print()` to see values in variables and then you can compare it with your calculations on paper.

Comment: First of all, you can only use ```return``` in a class or function in python.
Second, you can't compare a string in python. s[i] will only print out s' index (i).

Comment: You have to use `break` to exit this loop after `s = -1`. If you don't exit loop then it will run  `s[i]` again and it will meas `-1[i]` which is not correct.

Comment: `return` is used only in functions/method and it is used to assign result to variable - ie. `variable = function()`. You should use `print(s)` to see result.

Comment: shorter `97 =< s[i] <= 123` but you have to also check it for `s[i+k]` because `?` can be in second part of string. In python you don't have to use `( )` in `if ( ... )` and it makes code less readable. You could also use spaces around `=`, `==`, `>=`, `<=` to make code more readable. See more [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for PythonCode](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: instead of `if (s[i]==s[i+k]): continue` you could use `if s[i] != s[i+k] : s = -1` without `continue`

Comment: `k = len(s) // 2` ?

Comment: I have performed all the changes which you have mentioned. It is giving runtime error. Thanks in advance                                                                                                                s=input()
for i in range(len(s)//2):
 if 97<=s[i]<=123:
  if s[i] != s[i+k] : s = -1
 else: 
  if(s[i]>=s[i+k]):
   s[i+k]=s[i]
  else:
   s[i]=s[i+k]
print(s)

Comment: I am only giving s as input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but here's my attempt:

```py
s = list(input())
k = int(input())
for i in range(k):
    s[i] = s[i+k] if s[i] == '?' else s[i]
    s[i+k] = s[i] if s[i+k] == '?' else s[i+k]

print(''.join(s) if s[:k] == s[k:] else -1)
```

For inputs `ta?a` and `2` it will output `tata`, for `ab` and `1` it will output `-1`. Note that the second argument is redundant anyway since you said it's just half the length.